# Wolfram Mathematica - Minimization of an absolute error with respect to two parameters

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations, minimize

I want to minimize the absolute error between numerical solutions of two nonlinear ODEs. Here is the code I use:

```
\[Epsilon] = 10^-6;
Delta[t_] := 1/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] \[Epsilon]) Exp[-(t/\[Epsilon])^2]
f[t_] := 1/2 (1 + Tanh[100 t])

solw = NDSolve[{w''[t] + (w[t] + w[t]^2) w'[t] == f[t], w[0] == 0, 
    w'[0] == 0}, w, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Method -> "MethodOfLines"];
wsol[t_] := Evaluate[w[t] /. solw]

solG = ParametricNDSolve[{G''[t] + (G[t] + G[t]^2) G'[t] == 
     s2 Delta[t], G[0] == 0, G'[0] == 0}, G, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {s2}, 
   Method -> "MethodOfLines"];
GGreen[t_, s2_] := Evaluate[G[s2][t] /. solG]
Gsol[t_, s1_, s2_] := 
 s1 NIntegrate[GGreen[\[Tau], s2] f[t - \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

Then, I discretize the absolute error in time:

```
Table[Abs[wsol[t] - Gsol[t, s1, s2]], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

and use the command:

```
NMinimize[
 Max[Table[
   Abs[wsol[t] - Gsol[t, s1, s2]], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]], s1, s2]
```

However, this does not work because `s2` is not specified in the NIntegrate in `Gsol`.

Is there a way to minimize

```
Table[Abs[wsol[t] - Gsol[t, s1, s2]], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]]
```

with respect to `s1` and `s2` simultaneously?

For the sake of simplicity, `s2` can be restricted to `[-2,2]`.

Comment: you should post this on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer.

```
\[Epsilon] = 10^-6;
Delta[t_] := 1/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] \[Epsilon]) Exp[-(t/\[Epsilon])^2]
f[t_] := 1/2 (1 + Tanh[100 t])

solw = NDSolve[{w''[t] + Exp[w[t]] == f[t], w[0] == 0, w'[0] == 0}, 
   w, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Method -> "MethodOfLines"];
wsol[t_] := Evaluate[w[t] /. solw]

solG = ParametricNDSolve[{G''[t] + Exp[G[t]] == s2 Delta[t], 
    G[0] == 0, G'[0] == 0}, G, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {s2}, 
   Method -> "MethodOfLines"];
GGreen[t_, s2_] := Evaluate[G[s2][t] /. solG]
Gsol[t_, s1_, s2_] := 
 s1 NIntegrate[GGreen[\[Tau], s2] f[t - \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

interpol = 
  ListInterpolation[
   Table[Gsol[t, s1, s2], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}, {s2, -5, 5, 0.1}], {{0, 
     1}, {-5, 5}}];

NMinimize[{Max[
   Table[Abs[wsol[t] - interpol[t, s2]], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]], -5 <= s2 <=
    5}, {s1, s2}]
```

However, one needs to be careful with choosing the range of `s2` in the NMinimize. For `-1 <= 2 <=2` the solution is better than for `-3 <= s2 <=3`. This means that there might be a better solution.